# Weird (invalid?) stacktrace in android?

Tags: android, stack-trace

This is probably more about curiosity, not the wish to fix a problem, because it occurred seemingly randomly and only once. However, perhaps it may shed some light on some obscure aspects of java or android.

We use the [Lightstreamer](http://www.lightstreamer.com/) library, and in essence it's a streaming library, for which we register a simple listener which gets called whenever the streaming provides new values.

I've encountered an exception in my application, and inspected the stacktrace in logcat. I cannot figure out what's going on there. Here is the (relevant) top of the trace:

```
11-25 15:06:50.770 E/AndroidRuntime( 3100): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 15:06:50.770 E/AndroidRuntime( 3100): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 15:06:50.770 E/AndroidRuntime( 3100):     at com.lightstreamer.ls_client.UpdateInfoImpl.getNewValue(UpdateInfoImpl.java:142)
11-25 15:06:50.770 E/AndroidRuntime( 3100):     at com.ourapp.view.ShrinkingTextViewHelper.onMeasure(ShrinkingTextViewHelper.java:30)
11-25 15:06:50.770 E/AndroidRuntime( 3100):     at com.ourapp.view.ButtonEx.onMeasure(ButtonEx.java:67)
11-25 15:06:50.770 E/AndroidRuntime( 3100):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
```

And here is `ShrinkingTextViewHelper.java` in its entirety:

```
package com.ourapp.view;

import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt;

/**
 * Check text size on view and change the text size if it's width not fit to control's width  
 *
 */
public class ShrinkingTextViewHelper {
    public static void onMeasure(ShrinkingTextView view, int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        CharSequence text = view.getText();
        view.onMeasureSuper(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        
        TextPaint paint = view.getPaint();
        
        float paddings = view.getPaddingLeft() + view.getPaddingRight();
        
        paint.setTextSize(view.getInitialTextSize());
        
        float size = paint.getTextSize();
        while (size >= view.getMinTextSize()
                && paddings + paint.measureText(text, 0, text.length()) > view.getMeasuredTextWidth()
                && (view.getLineCount() == 1 || view.getLineCount() > view.getMaxLines())) {
            paint.setTextSize(--size);
            view.setText(text);
            view.onMeasureSuper(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
        
line 30:if (paddings + paint.measureText(text, 0, text.length()) > view.getMeasuredTextWidth()) {
            view.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `ButtonEx` class which is also present in the stacktrace:

```
package com.ourapp.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.text.method.SingleLineTransformationMethod;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.ourapp.R;
/**
 * Extended button class. It could shrink text on the face.
 *
 */
public class ButtonEx extends Button implements ShrinkingTextView {
    private static final float DEFAULT_MIN_TEXT_SIZE_DP = 10;
    
    private float minTextSizePx;
    private float initialTextSize;
    private int maxLines;
    
    /**
     * Class constructor
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public ButtonEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        
        TypedArray t = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ButtonEx);
        minTextSizePx = t.getDimension(R.styleable.ButtonEx_minTextSize, dipToPixels(DEFAULT_MIN_TEXT_SIZE_DP));
        
        t.recycle();
        
        int att[] = new int[] { android.R.attr.singleLine };
        t = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, att);
        boolean singleLine = t.getBoolean(0, true);
        boolean hasSingleLine = t.hasValue(0);
        t.recycle();
        
        att = new int[] { android.R.attr.maxLines };
        t = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, att);
        
        boolean hasMaxLines = t.hasValue(0);
        
        if (singleLine && hasSingleLine) {
            maxLines = 1;
        } else {
            maxLines = t.getInteger(0, 1);
        }
        
        if (singleLine && hasSingleLine
                || !hasSingleLine && !hasMaxLines) {
            setTransformationMethod(new SingleLineTransformationMethod());
        }
        
        setMaxLines(maxLines);
        t.recycle();
        
        att = new int[] { android.R.attr.textSize };
        t = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, att);
        initialTextSize = t.getDimension(0, 0);
        t.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        ShrinkingTextViewHelper.onMeasure(this, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
    
    private float dipToPixels(float dip) {
        return dip * getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }

    /**
     * Get min size of text on title.
     */
    public float getMinTextSize() {
        return minTextSizePx;
    }

    /**
     * Called to determine the size requirements for this view and all of its children. 
     */
    public void onMeasureSuper(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    /**
     * Get text width
     */
    public int getMeasuredTextWidth() {
        return getMeasuredWidth();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get max lines number. It parsed from XML attributes. Default value is 1.
     */
    public int getMaxLines() {
        return maxLines;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before,
            int after) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
        requestLayout();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get initial text size.
     */
    public float getInitialTextSize() {
        return initialTextSize;
    }
}
```

As you might guess, there is no, nor has ever been, a single reference to the lightstreamer library in a helper which is just responsible for some measuring of custom views. Which makes me think this is a bug in the Dalvik VM or something.

BTW, the application was built as usual, in Eclipse.

And yes, the text on the button does *not* come from lightstreamer-provided values, I can guarantee that.

Comment: How is it weird/invalid again? Clearly there is an NPE from within the `getNewValue` method being invoked from `onMeasure`. If nothing invoked it, well, then it could never be executed to generated said exception (and stacktrace).

Comment: it's that there is no sign of calling `getNewValue` from `onMeasure`

Comment: I *really* doubt that: a "bug" of this sort would invalidate pretty much all sanity in trusting the Dalvik VMs ability to function. Paste the entire `onMeasure` method?

Comment: I understand your doubt :) I've included the whole `ShrinkingTextViewHelper` and `ButtonEx` classes

Comment: Can you point which is line 30 in ShrinkingTextViewHelper?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the correct file/class :-)

The exception comes from the class `ShrinkingTextViewHelper` in `com.ourapp.view` while the class posted lives in `com.ourapp`.

Happy coding.

Comment: sorry, I've edited the true package name out. will fix it right now

Comment: @neutrino No idea then. Make sure the builds are current-to-source and are really as expected.

Comment: thanks for trying anyway :) I was just hoping someone could tell me a fairy-tale about stack unwinding or some corrupted registers.. I can be quite a daydreamer at times :)